# Number of $3 \times 3 \times 3$ magic cubes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A $3 \times 3 \times 3$ magic cube is a three-dimensional array of the consecutive integers $1$ through $27$, with the special property that the sum along any row, any column, any pillar, or any of the four space diagonals is equal to the same number. (Rotations of a certain solution are considered the same solution and therefore not counted.)

How many different $3 \times 3 \times 3$ magic cubes are there?

I got that the sum of each of these should be equal to $\frac19\left(\frac{27\cdot28}{2}\right)=42$, but I have no idea how to proceed after that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You've found that each 'line' sums to $42$. The middle number shares a line with every other number. In particular, it shares a line with the number $27$, so it is at most $42-27-1=14$. It also shares a line with the number $1$, so it is at least $42-1-27=14$. Hence the middle number must be $14$. Then the other $26$ numbers are placed in opposing pairs that sum to $42-14=28$.

Comment: @Servaes Oh, thank you, that helped me understand it now :)

Comment: One can take similar reasoning much further, but it becomes a bit too much for a comment. It's a good exercise to see how far you can get in determining all magic cubes with just pen and paper.

Comment: @Servaes your excellent indications should be written as an answer (with for example reference to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MagicCube.html)

Answer (score -1):

Up to rotation and reflection, there are [four](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SemiperfectMagicCube.html).

Comment: Please, if possible, try to put more information. (For example, giving the relevant references that are mentioned in the link you provide would be desirable.)